# comparing two data frames using r

Tags: r

I am new to R, apologies in advance for any issues with my question.
So, I have two data frames.

My first data frame has a list of people and the ethnicity of these people. Like below (a small portion of actual data):

data_frame_1:

```
name            ethnicity            
Mario Gonzales  hispanic
James R. Santi  white
A. Williams     asian
```

My second data frame just has a list of people. Like below (a small portion of actual data).

data_frame_2:

```
name
Mark Johnson
A. Williams 
James R. Santi
Kelly Wu
```

I am trying to produce a data frame that lists people in data frame 2 with their ethnicities (using the given information in data frame 1).So my desired output is a data frame that looks like this:

desired_data_frame_1:

```
name            ethnicity
A. Williams     asian
James R. Santi  white
```

I also want to create another data frame with unique names found in data frame 2 (names not found in data frame 1.) Like below:

desired_data_frame_2:

```
 name
 Mark Johnson
 Kelly Wu
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Look at `merge` and `unique` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the different names using `setdiff`.

```
## Data below
setdiff(input2$name, input1$name)
[1] "Mark Johnson" "Kelly Wu"
```

### Data

```
input2 = read.table(text="name
'Mark Johnson'
'A. Williams' 
'James R. Santi'
'Kelly Wu'",
header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

input1 = read.table(text="name            ethnicity
'A. Williams'     asian
'James R. Santi'  white",
header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```